# Where are the default Adobe Illustrator fonts found when installed?

Tags: fonts, adobe-illustrator

I need a copy of the `Myriad-Roman` font that is the default font for Adobe Illustrator.  I have Illustrator installed but I need to put the font on my sever so my PDF DLL can read the font since my PDF is using that `Myriad-Roman` font.

Please don't get distracted about the PDF part - I just need to know how to find the font wherever Adobe installs it when I install Illustrator (CS5).

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but I believe all fonts reside in the fonts directory which is in your Windows directory, so try looking in something like c:\Windows\fonts

Comment: First place I looked - it's not in there but it's clearly usable as a font choice from Adobe Illustrator though so it has to be somewhere.  

I thought Jeremy's post on this page (http://forums.adobe.com/thread/395641) was going to be the answer but that must be the location for an older version of Illustrator or something because it wasn't there either.

Comment: I can confirm that for AI CS2, the file `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Fonts\Reqrd\Base\wmr_____.pfm` is present and is Myriad Roman.  Odd that they would move it for CS5.

Comment: This Google search shows where others have found it in their directory structures... http://www.google.com/search?&ie=UTF-8&q=wmr_____.pfm+intitle:index